# Is SQL Server's Remote Login Timeout setting equivalent to setting Connection Timeout value in connection string?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, connection-string, connection-timeout

In SQL Server Advanced properties there is `Remote Login Timeout` setting within the `Network` section which defaults to 20 seconds.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175136.aspx

Is this setting equivalent to setting the `Connection Timeout=XX";` within the connection string or not, and if not, is there a way to change default `Connection Timeout` on the server itself instead of modifying connection strings to add this setting?

To me, MSDN is not clear on this, it's not clear if this is referring to remote login to that server for which the setting is specified or remote login from that server to other servers...

Answer (score 3):

Remote Login Timeout is set on the SQL Server side. In only affects Logins FROM the SQL Server to other Database Servers, eg. linked Servers or distributed transactions.
So here the SQL Server is the Client opening an connection.

The client connecting to the Server has to set the "Connection timeout" within the connection string if required.

The Server would not be able to measure the time the Client already tries to connect. It might eg. result in a delay in in Name Resolution at the Name Server side or when verifying the Kerberos token.

Also see
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177457(v=sql.105).aspx